# Access to object property php

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to acces to range but is tnot working

```
  $json = '{"range":[[1,2,20],[3,4.5]]}';
  var_dump(json_decode($json->'range'));//doesn't work
  var_dump(json_decode($json['range']));//doesn't work
```

Whay is the way to acces to range?

Comment: json_decode($json, true)

Answer (score 2):

You need to `json_decode()` your JSON string first to turn it into an object. After that you can access the object properties with the `->` operator.

So the correct way is this

```
var_dump(json_decode($json)->range));
```

But it is more readable if you split it into multiple statements:

```
$decoded = json_decode($json);

var_dump($decoded->range);
```

Answer (score 1):

you must use this one.

```
json_decode($json)->range;
```